R for loop to iterate through pages when search results are not maintained simply across page navigations
Here is the structure of my the button for the pages (there is no "next" button, only buttons for each page, from page 1 to 24)"inspect" results for the button for page 1
Here is my current R code, it doesn't work because the current code uses a URL to navigate through pages that assumes that simply changing the query parameter for the page number (&PROD_isoorg_en%5Bpage%5D=%d) will correctly navigate to the search results for "packaging". This does not reflect the actual behavior of the website as the search results are not maintained across page navigations in this manner. I do not know exactly how. How can i solve this ?
  library(RSelenium)
  library(rvest) 
  library(dplyr) 
  library(stringr)
  library(netstat)

  Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "English")
  rs_driver_object <- rsDriver(browser = 'firefox', verbose = FALSE, port = free_port(random = TRUE), chromever = NULL)

  remDr <- rs_driver_object$client
  remDr$open()
  remDr$navigate('https://www.iso.org/search.html?PROD_isoorg_en%5Bmenu%5D%5Bfacet%5D=standard')

  Sys.sleep(3)

  # Accept cookies by clicking the button, identified now by its class instead of ID
  cookie_accept_button <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', '//*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]')

  Sys.sleep(0.5)

  #Move cursor
  remDr$mouseMoveToLocation(webElement=cookie_accept_button)

  Sys.sleep(1)

  cookie_accept_button$click()

  # search for packaging 

  Sys.sleep(3)
  search_input <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', '#autocomplete-1-input')
  search_input$sendKeysToElement(list("packaging"))
  Sys.sleep(3)

  # locate the search button to press it
  search_button <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', '#autocomplete-1-label > button:nth-child(1) > svg:nth-child(1)')
  search_button$click()
  Sys.sleep(5)

  # Initialize an empty data frame to store ISO data
  iso_data <- data.frame(PublicationDate = character(),
                         NumberOfPages = character(),
                         NormNumber = character(),
                         TitleISO = character(),
                         SubtitleISO = character(),
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 


  # Function to extract all ISO on the current page
  extract_all_ISO_on_page <- function() {
    iso_data # Referencing the variable to append data

    iso_pages <- remDr$findElements(using = "class name", "h5.card-title")
    for (ISO_page in iso_pages) {
      Sys.sleep(4)
      # Extract the link contained in the element with class 'h5.card-title'
      # Assuming the ISO_page element is correctly referenced for RSelenium, which might need       adjustment
      page_to_open <- ISO_page$getElementAttribute("href")[[1]]

      # Open a new tab with the link and switch to it
      remDr$executeScript(sprintf("window.open('%s');", page_to_open))
      remDr$switchToWindow(remDr$getWindowHandles()[[2]])
      Sys.sleep(1)

      # Data extraction logic : 
      publication_date_elements <- remDr$findElements(using = 'xpath', "/html/body/main/div[1]/section[2]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/div[2]/span")
      publication_date <- publication_date_elements[[1]]$getElementtext()[[1]]
      number_pages_elements <- remDr$findElements(using = 'xpath', "/html/body/main/div[1]/section[2]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/div[2]")
      number_pages <- number_pages_elements[[1]]$getElementText()[[1]]
      norm_number_elements <- remDr$findElements(using = 'xpath', "/html/body/main/div[1]/section[1]/div/div/div[1]/nav/h1")
      norm_number <- norm_number_elements[[1]]$getElementtext()[[1]]
      title_iso_elements <- remDr$elements(using = 'xpath', "/html/body/main/div[1]/section[1]/div/div/div[1]/nav/h2")
      title_iso <- title_iso_elements[[1]]$getElementtext()[[1]]
      subtitle_iso_elements <- remDr$findElements(using = 'xpath', "/html/body/main/div[1]/section[1]/div/div/div[1]/nav/h3")
      subtitle_iso <- subtitle_iso_elements[[1]]$getElementtext()[[1]]


      # Append to the global iso_data dataframe
      iso_data <<- rbind(iso_data, data.frame(
        PublicationDate = publication_date,
        NumberOfPages = number_pages,
        NormNumber = norm_number,
        TitleISO = title_iso,
        SubtitleISO = subtitle_iso,
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE # Avoid factor conversion
      ))

      # Close the tab and switch back to the main tab
      remDr$closeWindow()
      remDr$switchToWindow(remDr$getWindowHandles()[[1]])

      cat("\tData from a new ISO captured.\n")
    }
  }





  # Function to iterate through pages and extract ISO data
  cycle_through_pages <- function() {
    index <- 2

    for (index in 2:24) {
      extract_all_ISO_on_page()
      cat(sprintf("Trying index: %d\n", index))
      
      # Navigate to the next page using constructed URL
      next_page_url <- sprintf("https://www.iso.org/search.html?PROD_isoorg_en%%5Bquery%%5D=packaging&PROD_isoorg_en%%5Bmenu%%5D%%5Bfacet%%5D=standard&PROD_isoorg_en%%5Bpage%%5D=%d", index)
      remDr$navigate(next_page_url)

      Sys.sleep(2)
    }
    cat("Success! All data collected!\n")
  }

  Sys.sleep(4)
  cycle_through_pages()

  # Don't forget to close the browser session when done
  remDr$close()

Could anyone help me solve my problem of navigation across pages, maintaining the "packaging" search results, to scrape the results of the ISO website ?
  library(RSelenium)
  library(rvest) 
  library(dplyr) 
  library(stringr)
  library(netstat)

  Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "English")
  rs_driver_object <- rsDriver(browser = 'firefox', verbose = FALSE, port = free_port(random = TRUE), chromever = NULL)

  remDr <- rs_driver_object$client
  remDr$open()
  remDr$navigate('https://www.iso.org/search.html?PROD_isoorg_en%5Bmenu%5D%5Bfacet%5D=standard')

  Sys.sleep(3)

  # Accept cookies by clicking the button, identified now by its class instead of ID
  cookie_accept_button <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', '//*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]')

  Sys.sleep(0.5)

  #Move cursor
  remDr$mouseMoveToLocation(webElement=cookie_accept_button)

  Sys.sleep(1)

  cookie_accept_button$click()

  # search for packaging 

  Sys.sleep(3)
  search_input <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', '#autocomplete-1-input')
  search_input$sendKeysToElement(list("packaging"))
  Sys.sleep(3)

  # locate the search button to press it
  search_button <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', '#autocomplete-1-label > button:nth-child(1) > svg:nth-child(1)')
  search_button$click()
  Sys.sleep(5)

  # Initialize an empty data frame to store ISO data
  iso_data <- data.frame(PublicationDate = character(),
                         NumberOfPages = character(),
                         NormNumber = character(),
                         TitleISO = character(),
                         SubtitleISO = character(),
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 


  # Function to extract all ISO on the current page
  extract_all_ISO_on_page <- function() {
    iso_data # Referencing the variable to append data

    iso_pages <- remDr$findElements(using = "class name", "h5.card-title")
    for (ISO_page in iso_pages) {
      Sys.sleep(4)
      # Extract the link contained in the element with class 'h5.card-title'
      # Assuming the ISO_page element is correctly referenced for RSelenium, which might need       adjustment
      page_to_open <- ISO_page$getElementAttribute("href")[[1]]

      # Open a new tab with the link and switch to it
      remDr$executeScript(sprintf("window.open('%s');", page_to_open))
      remDr$switchToWindow(remDr$getWindowHandles()[[2]])
      Sys.sleep(1)

      # Data extraction logic : 
      publication_date_elements <- remDr$findElements(using = 'xpath', "/html/body/main/div[1]/section[2]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/div[2]/span")
      publication_date <- publication_date_elements[[1]]$getElementtext()[[1]]
      number_pages_elements <- remDr$findElements(using = 'xpath', "/html/body/main/div[1]/section[2]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/div[2]")
      number_pages <- number_pages_elements[[1]]$getElementText()[[1]]
      norm_number_elements <- remDr$findElements(using = 'xpath', "/html/body/main/div[1]/section[1]/div/div/div[1]/nav/h1")
      norm_number <- norm_number_elements[[1]]$getElementtext()[[1]]
      title_iso_elements <- remDr$elements(using = 'xpath', "/html/body/main/div[1]/section[1]/div/div/div[1]/nav/h2")
      title_iso <- title_iso_elements[[1]]$getElementtext()[[1]]
      subtitle_iso_elements <- remDr$findElements(using = 'xpath', "/html/body/main/div[1]/section[1]/div/div/div[1]/nav/h3")
      subtitle_iso <- subtitle_iso_elements[[1]]$getElementtext()[[1]]


      # Append to the global iso_data dataframe
      iso_data <<- rbind(iso_data, data.frame(
        PublicationDate = publication_date,
        NumberOfPages = number_pages,
        NormNumber = norm_number,
        TitleISO = title_iso,
        SubtitleISO = subtitle_iso,
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE # Avoid factor conversion
      ))

      # Close the tab and switch back to the main tab
      remDr$closeWindow()
      remDr$switchToWindow(remDr$getWindowHandles()[[1]])

      cat("\tData from a new ISO captured.\n")
    }
  }





  # Function to iterate through pages and extract ISO data
  cycle_through_pages <- function() {
    index <- 2

    for (index in 2:24) {
      extract_all_ISO_on_page()
      cat(sprintf("Trying index: %d\n", index))
      
      # Navigate to the next page using constructed URL
      next_page_url <- sprintf("https://www.iso.org/search.html?PROD_isoorg_en%%5Bquery%%5D=packaging&PROD_isoorg_en%%5Bmenu%%5D%%5Bfacet%%5D=standard&PROD_isoorg_en%%5Bpage%%5D=%d", index)
      remDr$navigate(next_page_url)

      Sys.sleep(2)
    }
    cat("Success! All data collected!\n")
  }

  Sys.sleep(4)
  cycle_through_pages()

  # Don't forget to close the browser session when done
  remDr$close()

Could anyone help me solve my problem of navigation across pages, maintaining the "packaging" search results, to scrape the results of the ISO website ?
